# Change Form with Ajax, store Elements in Session

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I like to filter data sets, but I have so many different filters, that I can't load them all at once in the subformular I am using to select them. So I thought I load one by one using Ajax, my PHP-Script sucessfully produce the first part of the formular. It looks like this:

```
<form action="select_filter.php" method="POST">
<div name="formin" id="formin">
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="11"><button onclick="javascript: plusMinTen(0);" type="button">&lt;&lt;&lt;</button></td>
                <th>Filter</th>
                <td rowspan="11"><button onclick="javascript: plusMinTen(10);" type="button">&gt;&gt;&gt;</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript: this.checked ? takeOut(this.value) : takeIn(this.value) ;" id="filter" value="1" name="filter">Filterwert1</td>
            </tr>
            ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Filter X">
```

The navigation however don't work. I don't see what im doing wrong, list.php does it jobs when run normaly:

```
<script>
      $(function() {
          function plusMinTen(from){
              $.get(
                  "list.php"
                  {
                      from: from,
                  },
                  function(list){
                      $('#formin').html(list);
                  }
              );
          }

          function takeIn(into){
              alert("in"+into);
          }
          function takeOut(out){
              alert("out"+out);
          }
      });
    </script>
```

The functions takeIn and takeOut should add or remove the values temporary to SESSSION array and I have good idea how to do it, but I need to fix this AJAX-Problem first. Another thing I used alert to test if my JS works and it does, but I noticed something strange:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript: this.checked ? alert('in'+this.value) : alert('out'+this.value) ;" id="filter" value="14" name="filter">value14</td>
```

The Value should be taken in when I check the box and out when I uncheck it but in this way it seems visa versa. Because I suspeceted something along this lines:

```
if(this.checked){
      takeOut(this.value);
}else{
     takeIn(this.value);
}
```

but obviously it works the other way round can someone explain?

Comment: _“The Value should be taken in when I check the box and out when I uncheck it but in this way it seems visa versa”_ – that’s because the `click` event fires before the status of the checkbox is actually changed – use the `change` event instead.

Comment: Yeah now I get it. But the onChange also seems to fire before the status is changed. Well it doesn't matter really as long as it works.